# Commutator subgroup of (H,K)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem in Hungerford.

Thomas W. Hungerford, *Algebra*, 1st edition 1974, exercise 3 in section II.7:

> 3. If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, let $\left(H,K\right)$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by the elements $\left\{ hkh^{-1}k^{-1} \mid h \in H, \  k \in K \right\}$. Show that
>
> (a) $\left(H,K\right)$ is normal in $H \vee K$.
>
> (b) If $\left(H, G^{\prime}\right) = \left<e\right>$, then $\left(H^{\prime},G\right) = \left<e\right>$.
>
> (c) $H \triangleleft G$ if and only if $\left(H, G\right) < H$.
>
> (d) Let $K \triangleleft G$ and $K < H$; then $H / K < C\left(G / K\right)$ if and only if $\left(H, G\right) < K$.

[**EDIT**: I took the liberty to replace the $\varepsilon$ signs by $\in$ signs, since nobody has used $\varepsilon$ for containment in the last 20 or so years (and rightly so).]

I solved part (a) and (c), but I am stuck in other parts.

Comment: Could you clarify the notations?

Answer (score 1):

Out of old habit, I will write  $[x, y] = x^{-1} y^{-1} x y$, and $x^{y} = y^{-1} x y = x [x, y]$, but the following can be easily adapted to your notation.

(d) is a matter of spelling out the definitions: please try, and come back if you don't succeed. Just recall that $A \le C(B)$ iff $[A, B] = \{ e \}$.

As to (b), use the [Hall-Witt identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_subgroups_lemma#Proof_and_the_Hall.E2.80.93Witt_identity)
$$
[[x, y], z]^{y^{-1}} \cdot [[y^{-1}, z^{-1}], x]^z\cdot[[z, x^{-1}], y^{-1}]^x = e.
$$
with $x, y \in H$, and $z \in G$. The second and third term equal $e$ as $[G', H] = \{e \}$, hence so does the first one.

Comment: it is more easy than I thought, but I did not know about the $A\leq C(B)$ iff $[A,B]=e$. Hall-Witt identity seems very useful. I will try write a proof for part (b) using it.

Comment: is there another way more easy without using Hall-Witt Identity